# Vite + ReactJS -> Not able to load app webview on Android 8 and below #16105

Tags: reactjs, vite

I've recently migrated my app from react to vite and have encountered issue of opening or loading app on mobiles with android 8(oreo) and below

I've tried using '@vitejs/plugin-legacy' and still not able to resolve the issue

To reproduce the issue

Launch any vite with ReactJs in dev or build + serve
Open android emulation from android studio and launch virtual device with Android 8 or below
Open the local-IP:localhost-Port
It just shows blank screen with no errors and warns

If someone has resolved this issue kindly help me out

```
export default defineConfig({
  // for production build environments only
  build: {
    // minimum support es2015
    target: 'es2015',
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8009,
    strictPort: true,
    open: true,
    fs: {
      // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
      allow: [".."],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    // for production build environments only
    legacy({
      /**
       * 1. try changing these values
       * 2. run `pnpm build`, see the output files in dist directory
       * 3. run `pnpm preview`, see the actual loaded files in different versions of browsers
       */
      targets: ['cover 100%', 'not chrome < 15', 'not and_chr < 15', 'not safari < 5', 'not ios_saf < 5','not firefox < 45',' not and_ff < 45', 'not edge < 12', 'not ie < 9', 'not ie_mob < 9', 'not opera < 12.1', 'not op_mob < 12.1', 'not op_mini < 12.1', 'not android < 4.4'],
      renderLegacyChunks: true,
      additionalLegacyPolyfills: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
      modernPolyfills: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```